# JQuery integration with angularjs ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dropdown

I want to create custom dropdown for angular with jQuery and can't update angular model after jQuery `.val(newValue)` called. Why I use jQuery? Because in some pages I have few dropdowns with ~500 elements and pure angular render works very slow. Here is my link function of directive:

```
(scope, element) => {
  const parent = $(element);
  const field = parent.find('input');
  const list = parent.find('ul');
  scope.options.map(item => list.append(
    $('<li>')
      .text(item.text)
      .addClass(item.disabled && 'disabled')
      .data({
        value: item.value,
        disabled: item.disabled
      })
      .click(function () {
        const data = $(this).data();
        if (!data.disabled) {
          field
            .val(data.value)
            .trigger('change'); 
          // also tried => scope.model = data.value;
        }
      })
  ));
}
```

And this is template:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <input
    type="text"
    readonly
    placeholder="Select item"
    ng-model="model"
    ng-change="change">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Here on stackoverflow I found that should be `.trigger('change')` called, but it not help angular to change model. How can I update angular model?

Comment: who wants to use a drop down with 500 values in it?

Answer (score -1):

I found answer

```
scope.$parent.$apply(() => {
  scope.model = data.value;
});
```

Instead of

```
field
  .val(data.value)
  .trigger('change');
```